# increase Performance of the code

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How can rid of foreach and still get the same output. How can i increase the performance of the code by getting rid of the foreach loop.

```
public List<tblcourse> GetData(string value)
{
    testEntities1 db = new testEntities1();

    int v = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    testEntities1 t = new testEntities1();
    var u = (from g in t.tblcourses
             select new  { g.C_Id,  g.C_Name }).ToList();

    List<tblcourse> lisstt = new List<tblcourse>();

    foreach (var item in u)
    {
        tblcourse b = new tblcourse();
        b.C_Id = item.C_Id;
        b.C_Name = item.C_Name;
        lisstt.Add(b);
    }

    return lisstt;
}
```

Comment: THe two questions you pose are orthogonal, it is easy enough to not have the `foreach` loop but removing this will probably not improve performance.

Comment: You can increase performance by removing the lines of code that aren't used.  E.g. intialising 'db' and 'v'.

Comment: What is use of variable `v`? You might missing `where` condition on `tblcourses`..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var u = (from g in t.tblcourses
             select new tblcourse { C_Id = g.C_Id, C_Name = g.C_Name }).ToList();
```

Instead of selecting `anonymous type`, you can directly fill your custom Type.

Answer (score 4):

Let LINQ create the `tblcourse` objects instead of anonymous objects.

```
public List<tblcourse> GetData(string value)
{
    return (from g in db.tblcourses
            select new tblcourse() { C_Id = g.C_Id,  C_Name = g.C_Name }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd reduce it to something like:

*Note: I've removed the unused variables. I've also assumed that testEntities1 is an Entity Framework DbContext and requires disposing. I've also used the results variable to temporarily hold a reference to the list so it can be easily debugged by adding a breakpoint.*

```
public IList<tblcourse> GetData()
{
    using (var testContext = new testEntities1())
    {
        var results =
            testContext.tblcourses
                .Select(c => new tblcourse() { C_Id = c.C_Id, C_Name = c.C_Name })
                .ToList();

        return results;
    }
}
```

Of course replacing the `foreach` with a `LINQ` statement probably wont improve performance much, but it's probably more maintainable now.

You really want to look at a guide for best practices of naming class members in C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how do you get it to look cleaner (as the performance gain is negligable), you can do so like this:

```
public List<tblcourse> GetData(string value)
{
    return (from g in new testEntities1().tblcourses
             select new tblcourse { C_Id = g.C_Id, C_Name = g.C_Name }).ToList();
}
```